# I want to know what does "with" in this passage means

Tags: meaning, grammar, meaning-in-context

I took a practice exam for the entrance exam for Tokyo University, made by one company.

I had to translate a sentence I am going to talk about into Japanese.

But because of the word "with", I still have trouble in understanding the italic part of this sentence.

(I changed the format of the word "with" to show which "with" I am talking about.)

"This little girl, *looking at the complicated piece of reality we call a tree, `with` all its color, shapes, light and shade,* did not know which of these qualities to represent with a pencil, nor how to do it."

This is a part of one passage, so I attach a picture of it.
[image]

I understand this passage in this way:

Drawing a picture of something which looks real is not so simple as just copying it as it is.
To draw such a picture, you decide what is important and what is not, and then draw the important things properly.
The girl knew this (at least that it is not so simple), but when she was looking at the piece of reality we call a tree, she couldn't ignore any of its qualities (paid attention to all of its qualities), and then she couldn't draw such a picture.

So, I think the word "with" modifies **the verb "was looking"**.

The answer the company gave was like this.

When the girl was looking at the piece of reality we call a tree, which has colors, shapes, light and shade, she didn't know which of these qualities to represent with a pencil, nor how to do it.

So, the word "with" modifies **the noun "the piece of reality"**.

I don't know whether what I think or the answer is true.

If the company says is true, why "with **all its**", not just "with"?

I'm just studying English, so I cannot solve this by myself.

Could you give me some answer, please?

I'd be happy with any kind of answer, like "The company is right just because we say so."

P.S.

If you don't mind telling me the mistakes in grammar or usage, would you?

I'd be  so happy.

Comment: I am not quick to say the company is right just because, but the prepositional phrase starting *with* modifies this "piece of reality". If it helps you see it, remove the comma before *with*: a tree(,) with all its color, shapes, light and shade,"

Comment: Thank you a lot for answering.I still somewhat cannot understand why there is “its ”.  When with means “having”, usually possessive case perhaps won’t be used,  I think from my experience, like a girl with blue eyes.

Comment: The tree has color, shapes, light and shade. Does the sky have them? No, the tree or the piece of reality has those qualities. Owns those qualities. Its qualities. The girl sees all that with its color, shapes ...

Comment: So the former half of this sentence implies the whole, and to show this more clearly, the "with" propositional phrase modifies the piece of reality, (which means it has all its qualities). And then the latter half of this sentence implies choosing from the whole. (the whole ⇔ choosing from the whole) Thank you!

Comment: It's really just a matter of opinion how much of the preceding text you think is being "modified" by ***with*** here. The short answer is it just modifies ***a tree***, but we could include all of ***the complicated piece of reality we call a tree***. No way does it "adverbially" modify the verb ***looking*** though - that simply wouldn't make sense (unless we change the text after ***with*** to something like ***...with her limited understanding of which features to concentrate on***).

Comment: Thank you so much!  I first understood this “with” as “including”.  So I read the sentence like this: the girl looked at the piece of reality including all its qualities. Does this sentence make sense? And if this make sense, does the “including” propositional phrase also modify the noun, or can it modify the verb? Propositional phrases can often modify both nouns and verbs, I know, but it’s difficult to me how the kind of word it modifies changes and limits its meaning and usage....